# Lightning ltng:require in svg

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, svg-icon

In my Lightning Component, I have the following SVG file for a logo to be shown on the community builder page (when you install a Lightning Component).

```
//ComponentName.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="-237 360.9 120 120" style="enable-background:new -237 360.9 120 120;" xml:space="preserve" width="120px" height="120px">
<style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#40B4DE;}
</style>
<g id="Welcome">
  <g id="favicon">
    <g id="logo" transform="translate(0.000000, 1.000000)">
      <path id="Fill-6" class="st0" d="M-177.5,435.6c-5.6,0-10.1-4.5-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1c5.6,0,10.1,4.5,10.1,10.1
        C-167.4,431.1-171.9,435.6-177.5,435.6L-177.5,435.6z M-177.6,410.5c-8.2,0-14.9,6.7-14.9,14.9c0,8.2,6.7,14.9,14.9,14.9
        c8.2,0,14.9-6.7,14.9-14.9C-162.6,417.1-169.3,410.5-177.6,410.5L-177.6,410.5z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I need to use ltng:require instead because this is the right way to load external css and not use  tags as mentioned in [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html). However, whenever I apply the ltng:require tag, an error occurs saying that ltng:require is an invalid SVG tag.

Is this because ltng:require is only available within aura:component tag? If so, what would be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already figured it out ltng:require is only for .cmp files and its absolutely ok to load the external CSS as it is in your .SVG file .The .SVG file that you have looks ok .

Comment: Thanks, Mohith. I had to ask because Security Review failed and gave us this comment on all our SVG files.

Comment: Please schedule an office hour to discuss the issue with them